# Correct importing of classes

Tags: python

I have following folder structure:

```
root
   folder1
       file1.py
       file2.py
   folder2
       file3.py
```

How would the import of `file1.py` look like, if I want to import it in `file3.py`?
I tried different variants: `from folder1.file1 import *`, `from .folder1.file1 import *`, `from folder1 import file1`, and similar variations, unfortunately without success. Do I need to create an `__init__.py` file somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes `__init__.py` should be present in `root`, `folder1` and `folder2`

The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages, they just be an empty file

then you can do

```
from folder1 import file1
```

if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when `from package import *` is encountered

Comment: Incidentally if you wish to use the `from X import *` mechanism, you need to add them to the `__all__` variable in `__init__.py` so that they're exported. If you had a class or variable you wanted to make available you'd add it like so: `__all__ = ['foo','bar']`

Comment: I was sure that I wrote a comment... oh well. I still get an error message. `ImportError: No module named folder1`. And the folder definitely exists and has a `__init__.py` file inside.

Comment: add full path of `root` folder to sys.path, like sys.path.append(full_path_of_root_dir) before importing

Comment: There is no other workaround? That would mean that I can't really port my implementation to any other system, without setting the sys.path value again?!

Comment: @cherrun: you can define PYTHONPATH in env containing the path of root directory